# google admob undefined symbol for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

i have replaced older version of admob 6.6.1  with latest admob library  version 6.12.0 but i get this error although every thing is fine. I am using xcode 6.0.1, how to resolve this issue, any help?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEvent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventEditViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had same issue but i solved by adding eventKit and eventUIKit framework into my project. Hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 4):

This error is mostly because update of your **ADMOB SDK**.

1) Go to build phases->Open list of frameworks.

2) Locate `libGoogleAdMobAds.a`. Remove this file by pressing - sign.

3) Again add this `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` file back by pressing + sign and selecting "Add other". select this file from ADMOB folder of your project.

4) Clean, then build and run your project.

Also, check you have **-ObjC** set to **Other Linker Flags** in your project's target build settings and required frameworks are added.

Comment: same error again? Do you have older SDK folder still in your project?

Comment: Make sure it is in trash. Delete AdMob completely again and re-add it. If same error occur again, follow above steps. It should get solved.

Answer (score 1):

add Framework `EventKit` and `EventKitUI`.